# Implementing winding number algorithm to compute interior and exterior regions (OpenGL, c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, graphics

I need to implement the winding number algorithm for determining the interior and exterior regions of a (not necessarily simple) polygon.

What I have in mind is to break the polygon into simple regions(such that no region can be broken into 2 regions) and then using the winding number algorithm for 1 point in each regios, thus determining the nature of the entire region.
However, I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to compute said regions, and then I need to get a point inside each region(from there, implementing the winding number algorithm is quite simple).

Is there a simple and efficient algorithm that breaks a complex polygon to such regions?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you´re searching "tesselation" / "triangulation". Google will have results for that.

Comment: How do you represent the polygon?

Comment: @deviantfan Not quite, I need to know whick parts are inside the polygon. For example, [here](http://i.imgur.com/8p9LOnl.png) the interior regions are colored.

Comment: @Beta The polygon is represented with an array of vertices

Comment: And does a vertex have any kind of unique identifier? That is, if I suspect that two elements in the array represent the same vertex, can I do a discrete check or must I compare their coordinates?

Comment: @warforgad, did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the references of the wikipedia article on [points in polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Winding_number_algorithm) you can find a very useful [article](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html) on a efficient implementation of the winding number algorithm. The article is very clear and well written! It includes several examples, pseudo code and (luckily for you) a full implementation of the algorithm in c++. To understand the algorithm you can skip the mathematical background on winding numbers (the article briefly explains how they can be interpreted as homotopy class of the unit sphere) and just read on how and why the winding number can be expressed a lot more easily in this case.

Btw the winding number algorithm works perfectly fine on non-simple-polygons. Why would you want to split them into simple regions first? The above linked article also explains how you can use the crossing number to determine if a point lies within a simple(!) polygon. So i hope this gives you enough information to decide if you actually want to split your polygons first.

Comment: But I need to know which points to check, because I need to determine which regions are inside the polygon and which are outside. For example, [this polygon](http://i.imgur.com/8p9LOnl.png) is what the algorithm should do. Only the colored regions are interior.

Comment: That is exactly what the winding number algorithm does because the winding number is 0 for the non-colored regions in your example :) That is the case since the orientation of your polygon (or rather the order of the edges) is relevant to this algorithm - in your example the winding number is 0 because the polygon runs around the non-colored region clockwise once as well as counterclockwise once, which results in a winding number of `1-1=0`.

Comment: @H W I don't think you underrstood my intention. I know how the algorithm works, but I need to know **which** points to check in order to determine the interior regions. How do I get from a polygon a list of the regions? I need to know the regions(both interior and exterior), and then to check for every region(using a point inside this region) if it's interior. Or is there another way?

Comment: In this case I did in fact misunderstand your question. Could you explain a bit for what you need the regions so that we can think about other ways to represent them? The only thing i can think of so far to determine all regions is to check for intersections within your polygon and from there try to recursively find sub-polygons which are smaller than the previous polygon (this algorithm should not stop until there are no more intersections).

Comment: That's the question. The original phrasing is:"Write an algorithm for determining the inner regions of a polygon using the winding number rule. The input is the polygon's vertices. Implement the algorithm in OpenGL"